# Switch console problem

Tags: switch

i have a HP/3Com 5500-ei PoE-Switch, and i can't get a usefull response from the console. I have tried putty and HyperTerminal with following parameters:

- Speed 9600
- Data Bits 8
- Stop Bits 1
- Parity None
- Flow Control None

The console displays senseless characters only. Have anybody an advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having a very similar issue due to baud rate when trying to console into some Big-IP devices. While I was using 9600 their default was 19200. I would start there and see if perhaps different speeds could help.